# MYSQL WHERE CLAUSE: WHERE 'X' Exclude?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Is there a way to add to this mysql query to say where something is 'x' don't include it in the query?

```
function get_newest_members() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"member\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        ORDER BY date_created DESC
                        LIMIT 0 , 6";
            $newest_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($newest_set);
            return $newest_set;
        }
```

I want to add exclude where ptb_profiles.user_id = '99999' ?

Is this possible and if so can someone please show me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just add this in your condition

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
WHERE  ... AND ptb_profiles.user_id <> '99999'
```

As a sidenote, use single quote instead of double quotes so `\` is not needed

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM ptb_users INNER JOIN ptb_profiles
                ON ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
          WHERE ptb_users.account_type = 'member' AND 
                ptb_users.account_status = 'Active'    
          ORDER BY date_created DESC
          LIMIT 0 , 6";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude user having user_id `99999` from result

Just add

```
ptb_profiles.user_id != '99999'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

`SELECT * FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"member\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id AND ptb_profiles.user_id!='99999' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0 , 6`